# Can we bounty things on meta?

Tags: support, bounty

While researching up some examples for my recent suggestion for a new close reason, I found [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6674/14848).  It's pretty awesome, so I want to bounty it.  But I can't find the bounty button!  After some experimentation, it looks like it's actually just *not there*.  I have one on the main site but not here.

Is there some different amount of rep you need for meta bounties?  Is this a bug?  Is meta rep secretly tracked differently?  What's going on?

Answer (score 7):

Meta just [doesn't have the bounty feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78264/cant-post-bounty-on-a-per-site-child-meta) at all. ([MSE is the exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/cant-place-a-bounty-on-meta-questions).) The only canonical reason [I have found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78342/153219) is that

> There is no bounty system on per-site metas because *per-site metas have no reputation system*.

… but of course one then wonders why can't main site reputation be sacrificed for a bounty on meta! The sense I get is that SE just doesn't want bounties to influence the per-site child metas.

It's worth noticing too that on *main*, bountying a question makes it Featured, while on *meta*, Featured questions are controlled by a mod-only tag.

There is an open feature request though: [Bounty-like feature on metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231215/bounty-like-feature-on-metas).

Answer (score 5):

While bounties aren't really in line with the way meta works, I'm a big fan of showing appreciation for exceptional effort and I've been thinking I should do it more with exceptional meta participation as well. So here's a couple thoughts on how I might be able to do so:

- Meta's a bit more lax about comments than mainsite, so an appreciative comment is often not out of place. I shouldn't tack it onto an already bloated thread, though.
- Often I find active meta users on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) as well, where an @ ping can send them an appreciative word without adding to meta comment bloat. (If you're not an elected moderator, @ pings only work in chat if the name auto-completes; if it doesn't, the target user hasn't been in that room recently enough to continue getting notifications.)

Answer (score 3):

### No.

That's not a thing on meta--participation here is its own reward =)

Here's the stack-wide answer on the topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77687/311001